# React Native: Call function when a specific state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to call a function I define whenever a specific state changes?

For example:

```
function Component(props) {
   const [timerOn, setTimerOn] = useState(false);
   function startTimer() {
      setTimerOn(true);
      setTimeout(() => setTimerOn(false), 1000)
   }
   startTimer();
}
```

I need to call startTimer whenever setTimerOn(false) is called. How do I do that without calling startTimer every time the screen is rendered?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) is perfect here since you're already using React hooks. As stated in the official documentation -

> The Effect Hook lets you perform side effects in function components

So in your case,

```
function Component(props) {
   const [timerOn, setTimerOn] = useState(false);
   function startTimer() {
      setTimerOn(true);
      setTimeout(1000, () => setTimerOn(false))
   }

   // This code is for it to run for the first time when your component mounts. 
   // Think of it as the previous componentDidMount function
   useEffect(() => {
     startTimer();
   }, []);

   // This code is for it to run whenever your variable, timerOn, changes
   useEffect(() => {
     if (!timerOn) {
       startTimer();
     }
   }, [timerOn]); // The second parameters are the variables this useEffect is listening to for changes.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the hook [useEffect](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), this hook lets you execute code when any of the values inside the dependency array changes. You can use it like this

```
useEffect(()=> {
  doSomethingWhenFooChanges();
},[foo]);
```

Edit to enrich answer:

You can do something like this:

```
function Component(props) {
  const [timerOn, setTimerOn] = useState(false);
  function startTimer() {
     setTimerOn(true);
  }

  //Declaring timer variable
  let timer;

  useEffect(()=> {
    if(!timerOn) {
      timer = setTimeout(() => setTimerOn(false), 1000);
      startTimer();
    } else {
       //To prevent memory leaks you must clear the timer
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }
  }, [timerOn]);
}
```

In any case, I can't think of an scenario that you need to restart a timer when you can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval). That function executes a function every 'n' seconds. And it's used like:

```
setInterval(()=> {
  myFunctionToBeExecutedEvery1000ms();
}, 1000);
```

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using hooks. The useEffect hook will come to your rescue in this scenerio.  [More about it here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)